# Is it safe to catch and move hibernating fish?

Tags: fish, safety, goldfish, pond, winter

I have about 50 mixed types of goldfish and koi in an outdoor pond. I want to remodel the pond, expanding it to double the volume of water. I will relocate them temporarily to a 2000 gallon (7600 liters) swimming pool, which will be at the same temperature, use the same water, and I'll move the pump and medium to this pool. In fact, I'll just use the pump to pump the pond water directly to the pool so they have identical water conditions.

The problem is, we suddenly had winter. Although the pond pump has kept this water from freezing, most other water is frozen. The fish seem to have gone in hibernation, aren't' moving. Is it safe for me to catch them in a net and move them to the swimming pool? Or do I need to wait until it warms up and they leave hibernation? Is it likely they'll stay in hibernation for the rest of winter, even if we return to 70 degree Fahrenheit (21 °C) weather again this weekend?